# Delete the image from the server

Tags: php

I used a unlink method to delete the image

This image is located in this file folder only.

```
$filename = "warning-icon.jpg";
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
    echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
  } else {
    echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
  }
```

But the image is not deleted.

i have a server name called web04 that is my default server name (Client server name). I can't delete the images from the folder in this server. Same code i have checked in my system localhost, here image get deleted. But in web04 server, Image not get deleted.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which echo did you get?

Comment: You have to check the return value of `unlink()` to know whether a file was really deleted. See; http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php Failure to delete in Linux is usually related to permissions.

Comment: in echo it's displayed  "File name has deleted". But when i see in that folder. That image is not yet deleted.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have check this . Still the file is  not deleted.

Comment: @phpdeveloper: You have checked what? The return value of `unlink()` or the permissions? If so, what was the outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put a ticket to my web hosting team server. They gave a permission to delete the image. Now the image get deleted.

Thanks to all, those who are help me in this issue.

Answer (score 4):

define root directory:

```
$root_directory = '/home/myuser/htdocs';
```

Now delete the file:

```
if(unlink($root_directory.$_GET['file']))
    echo "File Deleted.";


 else
        echo "Couldn't delete the File.";
```

Comment: It is deleted in my local server. But not deleted in client server.

Comment: What client server? You want to delete from client machine?

Comment: i have a server name called web04 that is my default server name (Client server name). I can't delete the images from the folder in this server. Same code i have checked in my system localhost, here image get deleted. But in web04 server, Image not get deleted. Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As echo displayed "File name has deleted" and file still in directory, there are maybe another reasons like:

- You are looking in another directory
- You check file via browser, but browsers sometime cache it very hard
- This file is repeatedly created again by some agent/event

Looks like unlink really delete file as you make "file_exists" check.
Maybe try another check?

```
$filename = "warning-icon.jpg";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
  unlink($filename);
  echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "still exists!!!";
  }
} else {
  echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
}
```

Comment: 1. Iam Looking in the same directory that i have save this file.                    2. I have cleared the cache. same problem occurs.                                              3. No, In this folder there is no only two files one is Index.php(Code that i have given top) and another one is Image file (warning-icon.jpg).                  I have check all the possible conditions, But the image is not deleted. Please Give me the solutions. Thanks in advance.